# Передача аргументов в консоли

Tags: cmd, path, explorer

**При прописывании в командной строке этой команды:**

```
explorer %path%
```

> Открывается проводник с указаной в %path% папке.

**Например:**

```
explorer C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
```

> Откроется папка Desktop в проводнике.

**Так же можно прописать путь к файлу в %path% и тогда откроется файл.**

**Например:**

```
explorer C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

> Запуститься браузер

- **И вопрос:**

  **Можно ли к запускаемой программе передать аргументы? если да то как?**

*Например вот так (НЕ работает)*

```
explorer ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.youtube.com"
```

*Или так (НЕ работает)*

```
explorer "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/k notepad"
```

> Заранее Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, зачем использовать explorer, если можно в командной строке обратиться напрямую к chrome.exe или cmd.exe.

Как бы то ни было, explorer ожидает на вход путь до папки/файла, параметры "запускаемой программы" он обрабатывать не умеет. Это довольно логично: explorer открывает папку/файл прописанными в системе средствами. Он не разбирается, дали ему путь до exe-файла или doc-файла.

Список параметров командной строки explorer доступен, например, тут: http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm